# GCloud Build - Error: Dial tcp -- no such host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-build

Hi I have the following skaffold.yaml file

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta5
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: us.gc.io/directed-relic-285313/auth
      context: auth
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
  googleCloudBuild:
    projectId: directed-relic-285313
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
```

I setup everything to be able to leverage google cloud for development. I.e, I downloaded google cloud SDK, installed google cloud context, configured kubectl to use it and so on.

Now, when I run
`skaffold dev`
I see the following error

> ```
> Successfully built 4a849a25796b
> Successfully tagged us.gc.io/directed-relic-285313/auth:latest
> PUSH
> Pushing us.gc.io/directed-relic-285313/auth:latest
> The push refers to repository [us.gc.io/directed-relic-285313/auth]
> Get https://us.gc.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup us.gc.io on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
> ERROR: push attempt 1 detected failure, retrying: step exited with non-zero status: 1
> Pushing us.gc.io/directed-relic-285313/auth:latest
> The push refers to repository [us.gc.io/directed-relic-285313/auth]
> Get https://us.gc.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup us.gc.io on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
> ERROR: push attempt 2 detected failure, retrying: step exited with non-zero status: 1
> Pushing us.gc.io/directed-relic-285313/auth:latest
> ```

Any idea where to start to debug this? Or what could be causing the error?

Comment: Shouldn't the repo be us.gcr.io and not us.gc.io ?

Comment: yepppp I had a typo... ugh thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had a typo....
us.gcr.io... not us.gc.io

Thanks tarun_khosla